# Change Language in database by cliking the country flags

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

Litte bit long explanation. I have a database name "visitor" saved for people visiting my website (bilingual) :

1. id       = 1
2. session  = fdslup7nsop20ctlkbcf2f7016
3. country  = singapore
4. language = en

Based on that database, I can use the language (en) as a session to present my website in english version.

in my index.php, I use this script and it works :

```
$locallang=$pages->SelectLocalLanguage(); // pointed to $page class
$_SESSION['mylang'] =$locallang;

if ($_SESSION['mylang']=='en' {
   // show in english
  }else{
   // show in other language
 }
```

in the $page class :

```
public function SelectLocalLanguage() {
    $ses_id = session_id();
    $query  = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `visitors` WHERE session=? ");
    $query->bindValue(1, $ses_id);
       try {   $query->execute();
                 $result = $query->fetch();
    return $result ['language'];
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    } 
    }
```

In my topheader.php, I have several flag image represent every language (id, en, fr, ru ) and one of them is :

```
<li><a href="#" ><img src="/images/flags/id.png"></a></li>
```

Problem :

By clicking the flags image, I need to :

1. Change the 'language' record in database, and in the same time,
2. Refresh the page to see the result.

I have used many ways, but still stupid.

```
    <li><a href="#"  onClick="ChangeLang('id'); window.location.reload();return false;"><img src="/images/flags/id.png"></a></li>

<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeLangauge(lg) {
    alert("Change Language? Page will be Refresed..!!");
    url = "/includes/change-lang.php?newlang=" + lg;

}
</script>
```

Still no change by this way..

change-lang.php :

```
<?php
$lg=$_GET['newlang'];
$pages->ChangeLang($lg);
?>
```

in #pages Class :

```
public function ChangeLang($lg) {

    $ses_id = session_id();

    $query  = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `visitors` SET select_lang=? WHERE session=? ");
    $query->bindValue(1, $lg);

    try {
        $query->execute();


    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    } 
    }
```

Comment: considering the code you have written so far, you should at least make an attempt and post that, explaining the problem with it

Comment: The result is I have to refresh again to see the final result after the page reload and change database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can make the link go to the same page, with a GET variable at the end, such as `?lang=en`. Then, make a function that checks for that GET variable on page load, changing the database on its existence.

```
function changeLanguage() {
if(!isset($_GET['lang'])) return;
else {
    $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE visitors SET language = ? WHERE session = ?");
    $query->bindValue($_GET['lang'], session_id());
    try {   
        $query->execute();
    }
}
```

Assuming that happens before the example code you posted above, the functions you've created already should pick up the new database changes before the page is completely loaded, which would load the page in whatever the new language is.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier in the PHP script:

```
if ( isset($_GET['newlang']) ) {
    $pages->ChangeLang($_GET['newlang']);
}
```

And:

```
public function ChangeLang($lg) {

    $ses_id = session_id();

    $query  = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `visitors` SET select_lang=? WHERE session=? ");
    $query->bindValue(1, $lg);
    $query->bindValue(2, $ses_id);

    try {
        $query->execute();


    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    } 
}
```

And the flags links:

```
<li><a href="?newlang='id'"><img src="/images/flags/id.png"></a></li>
```